# Item size of Generators vs appended list vs manually written lists

Tags: python, memory, generator

does anyone know why there is a difference in size stored of a manually typed list (range_2) and "appended list" through a for loop (range_1)?
Also, the common conception is that generators save memory space. But why does 
(range_Range) actually take up more memory?

Thanks in advance!

```
import sys

range_Range = list(range(1,11))
range_1 = []
range_2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for i in range(1,11):

range_1.append(i)

print("size of range_1 is {} bytes".format(sys.getsizeof(range_1)))
print("size of 'range_Range' is {} bytes".format(sys.getsizeof(range_Range)))
print("size of range_2 is {} bytes".format(sys.getsizeof(range_2)))
```

Comment: your range_Range is a list, not a generator/iterator object. take the list() off of it and the size will drop. When you do that, you will see how you have to access the values in it one at a time.

Comment: But you would have to make the generator object a list, say, to process it wouldn't you?

Comment: No, you can just iterate over the `range` object directly. The whole point is that you **don't** have to materialize it into a list.